# How to filter data in a nested array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular Service which sends a data service call and returns an array of objects containing multiple layers of data.
I want to be able to filter thrhough that data and return only the object that contains a specific value.

```
        this.service.getRecords().pipe(
        map(item => item.filter(items => items.attributes['identifier'].value === '101723102')),
        tap(item => console.log(item)),

    ).subscribe();
```

The attributes[] has thosands of objects like the one stated below:

```
[20000]: {identifier:"1239213", something: "42142", something: "42142", something: "42142".....}
```

I am trying to filter and return the objects if the identifier is equal to something but am not sure how to access the value since it is nested and I cannot use dot notation.
Current code returns error: `Cannot read property 'identifier' of undefined`

[EDIT]:
This is the service I am using

```
export class DataViewerService {

_recordDetails: Observable<DataClass[]>;
```

// resource service contains code to retrieve data
constructor(private _resourceService: ResourceService,
) { }

```
    getRecords() {
    return this._recordDetails = this._resourceService.search(CONSTANT, {})
        .pipe(map(extractRecords))
        .pipe(shareReplay()) as Observable<Data[]>;

}


function extractRecords(result) {
const records = [];
if (!isNullOrUndefined(result)) {
    result.forEach(r => {
        if (!isNullOrUndefined(r['payload'])) {
            records.push(r.payload);
        }
    });
}
return records;
```

}

[EDIT]:
Items Object is as follows:

```
{
  attributes: [],
  descrtiption: "",
  name: "",
  label: ""
}

I need to access the objects within the attributes[] of filter which looks like
attributes: [
{
     identifier: "1243212",
     something: "",
...
}
```

This is the interface and the object returns is of type Data

```
export interface Data {
name: string;
label: string;
attributes: DataAttributes[];
```

}

```
interface DataAttributes {
    attributes: [
           identifier: string;
           something: string;
     ];
    something: string;
...
 
}
```

And the service returns the attributes[] which contains the values I want to filter

Comment: can you provide an example of items object ?

Comment: Hi @SupunDeSilva, thanks for the reply, I have edited the question to add a description of the items object

Comment: Your Interface model does not seem to align with the attribute array example

Comment: can you please add a cut-down version of a realistic example for Items Object having an entry or 2 inside attributes ?

I added an answer relying on the model interface you have provided

Answer (score 1):

It might work

```
map(item => item.filter(items => items.attributes['identifier'] && items.attributes['identifier'].value === '101723102')),
```

or

```
map(item => item.filter(items => item.attributes !== undefined && items.attributes['identifier'] != undefined && items.attributes['identifier'].value === '101723102'))
```

also it will be better if you edit DataAttributes like this:

```
interface DataAttributes {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    identifier?: any;
}
```

Comment: Hi @fro, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this still prompts the same type error: core.js:4002 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'identifier' of undefined

Comment: @rkras, then try to use this:
map(item => item.filter(items => items.attributes !== undefined && items.attributes['identifier'] !== undefined && items.attributes['identifier'].value === '101723102'))

Comment: No more type error but it seems to be returning the same object with 3000 nested objects, this filter should return 1 object as the identifier is unique. How would I return just that row of data in this method? Thanks in advance

Comment: Then you have to count items by identifier value and get object that count is only one.

Answer (score 0):

**Using New model interface as follows**

```
export interface DataModel {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  attributes: object[];
}
```

**Using a Mock Data as follows**

```
{
    attributes: [
        { identifier: '1239213', something: 100 },
        { identifier: 'foo', someOtherThing: 100},
        { identifier: '101723102', description: "101723102"},
        { notIdentifier: '101723102', description: "101723102"}        
    ],
    name: "",
    label: ""
}
```

**Using a Mock Data Service as follows**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { DataModel } from './models/data';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private mockData : DataModel = {
    attributes: [
        { identifier: '1239213', something: 100 },
        { identifier: 'foo', someOtherThing: 100},
        { identifier: '101723102', description: "101723102"},
        { notIdentifier: '101723102', description: "101723102"}    
    ],
    name: "",
    label: ""
  }

  private sbj : BehaviorSubject<{}> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.mockData);
  constructor() { }

  getRecords() {
    return this.sbj;
  }
}
```

**Do the following**

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  public filteredObjStr = ''
  constructor(private service: DataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getRecords().pipe(
        map(item =>   {
          if (item['attributes'] == null) {
            return []
          }
          return item['attributes'].filter(x => x['identifier'] === '101723102')
        }),
        tap(filteredAttribs => 
        {
          this.filteredObjStr = JSON.stringify(filteredAttribs, null, 2);
          console.log('filteredAttribs : ', filteredAttribs);
        })

    ).subscribe();
  }

  public filter_changed(value) {
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

**Example - Check App console**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvxxjk

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, this looks like it is close to what I am trying to achieve, however I am unable to use a mock object to pass straight through to the Behaviour Subject. There is code manipulating the data and the service I have written does retrieve data into the component when calling this.getRecords, I am just struggling to filter it as the identifier is nested in the attributes array... Any Idea how I may achieve this in the compoent using rxjs operators?

Comment: You do not need use the mock, All you have to do is use your `getRecords` method.
I had to use a mock as I did not have your data source.
Also if you can add a realistic example (cut down version) with actual content inside `attributes` for `Items Object` it will be a lot easier

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Sorry a bit new to this game, I know the question is terrible. I have added the item object in an edit which shows the values. I am affraid with your solution I am getting an error of cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Please see my latest edit of items object if you can, maybe that helps.

Comment: `cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` says the the property `attributes` does not not exist in your data that comes from the API. If you can add a cut-down version of the data that is returned from the API, I can help out. Having a null check might not fix your issue.

Comment: So the problem is your interface declaration of DataAttributes is a bit wrong. I'll update my answer in a bit

Comment: Check Now. Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not having an algorithm for this you can rely on lodash for these kind of operations with objects in Javascript (not Angular per se).

First install lodash (`npm install lodash`).

Since you want to filter by a nested key, you should use `filter` method with a function as predicate.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

// let's asume a variable called attributes holds your array of objects
const filteredData = _.filter(attributes, function(item) { return item.value === 'something'; })
```

I don't know if I understand the structure of your data. You can read de docs for `filter` [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter).

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Assuming your goal is to take your `Data` objects and select certain `DataAttributes` objects that matches some name, then you could do something like this:

1. map each `Data` item to its array of `attributes`
2. flatten those arrays of attributes to a single stream of `DataAttributes` objects
3. filter those `DataAttributes` objects by the desired `name`

```
const records: Observable<Data[]> = ...;
const selectAttribute = 'some name';
records.pipe(
  concatMap(records => records.map(({attributes}) => attributes)),
  concatAll(),
  filter(({name}) => name === selectAttribute)
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-62805815